# Spring integration sftp is not closing connections

Tags: spring, kotlin, sftp

When using SFTP spring integration, spring is not closing connection with our SFTP server and creates new one with each pool

My code

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun sessionFactory(): DefaultSftpSessionFactory {
        log.info("Creating SFTP session factory with $username@$host")
        val factory = DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true)
        factory.setHost(host)
        factory.setPort(22)
        factory.setUser(username)
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true)
        factory.setPassword(password)
        return factory
    }

 @Bean(name = ["certificateApplicationResponseSynchronizer"])
    fun certificateApplicationResponseSynchronizer(): SftpInboundFileSynchronizer {
        log.info("Creating SFTP certificate application response synchronizer")
        val sync = SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sessionFactory)
        sync.setRemoteDirectory(certificateResponseDirectory)
        sync.setFilter(SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter(navisionCertificateResponseFilenamePattern))
        sync.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true)
        return sync
    }

    @Bean(name = ["sftpCertificateApplicationMessageSource"])
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "navisionCertificateResponse", poller = [Poller(fixedDelay = "60000")])
    fun sftpCertificateApplicationMessageSource(): MessageSource<File> {
        log.info("Creating SFTP certificate application response message source")
        val source = SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(certificateApplicationResponseSynchronizer())
        source.setLocalDirectory(File("tmp$certificateResponseDirectory"))
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
        source.maxFetchSize = 20
        return source
    }
```

Looking at logs it looks like its opening new session with each pool, checks for new files and then it remains open forever. Because of that our SFTP is running out of RAM quickly